# How can I pin point a USB file transfer bottleneck in Unix?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, performance, usb-storage, data-transfer

I'm experiencing very slow data transfer speeds over USB 2.0 on my nix box and was wondering how I can pin-point the cause of the problem.

I've looked into iotop and top but the cpu and mem figures look normal (compared to guides I have checked).

The box which is affected is Ubuntu 12.04 32bit Server running on an Asus EEE 701 2G model and I am transferring from the OS over USB 2.0 to an external HDD (which transfers at 30MB/s+ on Windows 7 on other machine).

I get rsync write speeds of 1MB/s from OS to USB HDD which seems ridiculously slow. These speeds are consistent with other USB HDDs and sticks.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem here: http://superuser.com/questions/577135/transfering-files-over-usb2-0-500gb write speeds on mine are about 2 MB/sec on linux

Answer (score 1):

First, please make sure you actually have USB 2.0. Paste the output of the commands:

```
lsusb
lsusb -v
```

Install atop, then run atop as root:

```
apt-get install atop
atop
```

And start your transfer. Keep watching atop while the transfer is happening. Let it run a minute or so. Atop takes 10 s between updates.
Look for any colored lines (e.g. red lines).